# Adding a line break after certain set of characters in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file like this that contains something like this:

```
my_text=     """
    Giovinni Enrico
    I GIO MORET FMJ
    1.Air Jordan 2.Nike 3.Prada
    4.Dolce & Gabbana 5.2.2.Diesel
    Adriana Cazetto
    ADRE CX GF 1.Air Jordan 
    2.Adidas 3.LV
    4.2.8. Gucci """
```

I read them from a text file and I want to add a new line after numbers. Here is the current code that I have:

```
import re
#for folder, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
my_file = open("October 2014.txt", "r")
content = my_file.read()
my_list = list(range(1, 21))
my_real_list = []
for number in my_list:
    x = str(number) + "."
    my_real_list.append(x)
if any((c in my_real_list) for c in content):
     line = content.replace(c, "\n"+str(c))
```

How could I get the following output and write it to a new text file?

```
my_text=     """
    Giovinni Enrico
    I GIO MORET FMJ
    1.Air Jordan 
    2.Nike 
    3.Prada
    4.Dolce & Gabbana 
    5.2.2.Diesel
    Adriana Cazetto
    ADRE CX GF 
    1.Air Jordan 
    2.Adidas 
    3.LV
    4.2.8.Gucci """
```

Comment: Is ".. and write it to a new text file" a second question, separate from the numbers question? Do you have a problem with writing something to a text file?

Comment: No my problem is getting the following output

Comment: Is there a tab space before starting every line as shown?

Comment: oh no there is no tab space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?m) (?<!^)(?=\d+\.)
```

You can try this regex for matching the character to be replaced with newline, \n

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1y9NgX/2/)

In python,

```
new_content=re.sub(r'(?m) (?<!^)(?=\d+\.)','\n', content)
```

Comment: It's a new challenge & experience to touch-input an answer to stackoverflow in my win-tab:-)